# Responsive Nav menu project - two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project to create a responsive Nav Menu. My goal right now is to have the Nav Menu switch from displaying at top to displaying on the side for tablet devices (Screens under 800px wide).

In my media query I have the li's reverting back to a vertical alignment by setting float:initial; and have set float:left; for the main-nav div and float:right; for the content div. However, for some reason, the content div is still stacking under the main-nav div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border:none;
}

.content {
  width:100%;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:auto;
}

.main-nav {
  width:100%;
  max-width:1000px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:#004d99;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:none;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.main-nav ul {
  float:right;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding: 0px;
  border:none;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.main-nav li a {
  display:block;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.main-nav li {
  float:left;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:#004d99;
  color:#ffffff;
  border:none;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  margin:0px;
}

.main-nav li:hover {
  background-color:#0073E5;
}

.header {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.header img {
  width:100%;
}

/*Tablet Screens*/
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .main-nav {
    width:200px !important;
    height:800px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
    margin-left:0px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left !important;
    clear:none !important;
  }
  
  .main-nav ul {
    float:left !important;
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
  }
  
  .main-nav li {
    float:initial !important;
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
  }
  
  .content {
    float:right !important;
    clear:none !important;
  }
}

/*Mobile Screens*/
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .main-nav {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page02</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page03</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dgvvgqr2q/image/upload/v1456519063/5D4487FB-D2A2-4A96-8113-C671577B1DC1-header_tojssi.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you want a to play around my code, I have a CodePen here...
http://codepen.io/amobley1108/pen/JXPmpL

Comment: is that what you need ? http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/GZRZWw?editors=0100

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps. I am no fan of overruling css styles, so I put most of your nav into another mediaquery > 800px

```css
body {
  border:none;
  font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin:auto;
  max-width:1000px;
}

.main-nav {
  background-color:#004d99;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color:#ffffff;
  display:block;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.main-nav li:hover {
  background-color:#0073E5;
}

.header {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}

.header img {
  width:100%;
}

/*Desktop Screens*/
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
  .main-nav {
    height:40px;
  }

  .main-nav ul {
    float:right;
  }

  .main-nav li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    float:left;
  }
}
/*Tablet Screens*/
@media only screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width:800px) { 
  .main-nav {
    float: left;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width:200px;
  }   
  
  .content {
    float:right;
    width: calc(100% - 200px)
  }
}

/*Mobile Screens*/
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .main-nav {
      display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">   
    <div class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page04</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dgvvgqr2q/image/upload/v1456519063/5D4487FB-D2A2-4A96-8113-C671577B1DC1-header_tojssi.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```